# Does facebook require authentication for a trusted app?

Tags: java, facebook, oauth, facebook-apps, facebook-authentication

Once a user has trusted a facebook app, I'd like our backend java application to be able to post to facebook without ever requiring authentication in facebook again. Is this possible?

If it helps to give a scenario:

1. User visits `foo.com/trustFooApp`, this then navigates to and from facebook to do the authentication.
2. When returning from a successful authentication, the users identity (facebook username?) and date of birth are stored in a database table `PreviouslyAuthenticatedUsers`
3. A Java backend system is running and at midnight each day it queries the `PreviouslyAuthenicatedUsers` table to see if it is anyone's birthday today. If any are found with a birthday today it posts on their wall to say 'Happy Birthday!' without requiring authentication again.

Comment: Facebook authentication tokens can be persisted in your database, but you'll still need to reuse the persisted connection when interacting with fb

Comment: No it is not possible. You are not allowed to post predefined messages on peoples walls.

Comment: @Wizkid the messages aren't actually predefined, this is just an example - I'm looking to make posts on users walls that they have requested be shared but do so in batch at regular intervals

Comment: @kolossus Do the persisted connections timeout and therefore require re-authenication? If so, do you have any idea of the timeout interval?

Comment: So the user goes to your page and manually type in a bunch of messages and schedule them for later publishing? I think as long as the user manually type the message you are ok. Just store the access token and extend it for a 60 days access token

Comment: @WizKid you're right, that's exactly what they do. Do you know how long the tokens last for by default? Is the 60 day access token requested from Facebook after the initial token has been obtained and if so do the users need to authenticate this permission?

Comment: The default is a few hours and then you can extend it for one that works for up to 60 days. It is all described at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Comment: @WizKid that's great, thanks very much for your help. This answers my question so if you want to put it as an answer I'll mark as accepted.